# multiple insertion in php and mysql (insert into)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that inserts some data in two tables

```
<form name="modulo" method="post" action="inseriscio.php">
                Nordine&nbsp;<input id="nor" name="nor" value="Nordine"><br>
                Data ordine<input type="date" id="datao" name="dao" value="Data Ordine"><br>    
                Data consegna<input type="date" id="datac" name="dac" value="Data consegna"><br>
                <div id="contenitore">
                    <?php
                    $pro = 'sito';
                    $dd = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $pro);
                    $re = mysqli_query ($dd,"SELECT Codice, Nome FROM prodotti");
                    echo"<div class='box'>";
                    echo"Prodotto";
                    echo"<select class='inse' name='po'>";
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($re)){
                            echo"<option value=".$row['Codice'].">".$row['Nome']."</option>";}
                    echo"</select>";
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo"Quantit&agrave; <textarea name='qua' rows='1' cols='4'></textarea></div><br>";
                    ?> 
                             </div>
                    <br><button type="submit" id="ok">OK!</button><br>
                </form><input type="text" class ="num" id="num" name="num" value="numero"><button id = "aggi" onClick="agg()">Aggiungi</button>
```

This is the form. Using the "aggiungi," I create other select and textarea via a script (the number of new tag is given from the keyboard). Until everything is ok but when I fill out the form and send to the php page that just takes a value of select and textarea and not all. So if I have 5 not fit all 5 of the values that I enter but only one.

```
<?php
        $nordine = $_POST['nor'];
        $datao = $_POST['dao'];
        $datac = $_POST['dac'];
        $prodotto = $_POST['po'];
        $quantita = $_POST['qua'];

        $data = 'sito';
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $data);
        $result = mysqli_multi_query ($db, "INSERT INTO ordini (Nordine,DataO,DataC) VALUES('$nordine','$datao','$datac')");

        $result1 = mysqli_multi_query ($db, "INSERT INTO ordpro (Prodotto, Ordini, Quantita) VALUES('$prodotto','$nordine','$quantita')");
        echo"<p>
        Hai inserito un nuovo record <a href='ordini.php'> torna alla home </a>
    </p>";
    ?>
```

php code
I hope I was clear
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I clarify you are naming your new selects and textarea in the script?

> "(the number of new tag is given from the keyboard)" ?

so the newly create select and textarea have a new name? ie.

```
<select name='po' + currentIndex
```

and

```
<textarea name='qua' + currentIndex
```

If you aren't,you are only accessing the first 'po' and 'qua' form elements in your post handling code. If I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_multi_query like this :-

> `
>   sql = "INSERT INTO ordini (Nordine,DataO,DataC) VALUES('$nordine','$datao','$datac');";
>
> sql .= "INSERT INTO ordpro (Prodotto, Ordini, Quantita)VALUES('$prodotto','$nordine','$quantita')";
>
> if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
>   }`